# Pixley and Roy article request

Tags: gn.general-topology, paper-request

I'm trying to get a digital copy of the article "C. Pixley and P. Roy, Uncompletable Moore spaces,
Proc. Auburn Univ. Conf. (Auburn, Alabama, 1969), 75-85." but I have not been successful. Could you please share a copy of that article with me?

Comment: My guess was that perhaps these proceedings were the ancestor of http://topology.nipissingu.ca/ (formally also available at auburn.edu), but that journal was founded in 1976.

Comment: A quick search at the Auburn University library led me to [this catalog record](https://catalog.lib.auburn.edu/vufind/Record/468179). [This google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=pixley+%22uncompletable+moore+spaces%22+%22Transue%22&filter=0) strongly supports that the catalog record is for what you want (note Transue as editor). Maybe try interlibrary loan, which doesn't have to originate from Auburn by the way, because I've seen these older topology proceedings volumes on the library shelves in several Southeastern U.S. universities.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was visiting Auburn today and obtained a scan.

https://github.com/StevenClontz/research/blob/master/miscellaneous/SKM_C650i23042612550.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much Steven!